# Image classifier project

Tags: python

```
python predict.py /path/to/image checkpoint
```

what is the path to image here. i need to give an image as an input, the image is in a folder 1 which is in folder test, which is in the folder flowers. so i have written it as /flowers/test/1/image.jpg, but i am getting it as "no file or directory"

[image]

[image]

i have tried writing the statements in the image, as i said thats not working. i am doing a udacity nanodegree project AI programming with python.

Comment: A path starting with `/` is an absolute path. You need to write `flowers/test/1/image.jpg` without the leading slash.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the `flower/` directory is at the root of the file system, you shouldn't have a leading slash in front of the path. To reference the current directory, you should instead do `python predict.py ./flowers/test/1/image.jpg checkpoint`.

Comment: i got the output as invalid load key

Comment: @PriyaP what is the entire error message?

Comment: unpickling error '{' . invalid load key

Comment: pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '{'.

Comment: @PriyaP that sounds like a problem somewhere else, unrelated to passing the correct image path. I suggest you make a new question and include the relevant details.